# What is a better solution for too many in-app notifications

Tags: mobile-application, notification

With the current state of travel, there are many regulatory bits of information that need to be conveyed to users as they make a booking on our travel app. Here there are at least 4 separate notifications (some being quite lengthy text)that need to be conveyed to users even before they start looking for which their travel options on the app.

In the past this hasn't been a problem, my question is if there is a better solution to this than stacking them on top while pushing the content down.

[image]

Comment: How are these notifications linked to the booking process? Can you mention the type of notifications you have? Also is this a web view or a mobile view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the notifications are taking up too much space on the screen, you could add a notification tab that might have a signal when you have new notifications. That way, the user could check their notifications any time without taking up too much screen space

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this could be creating a 'dropdown' toggle to show all the notifications, with a line like "There are 4 notifications that need your attention [↓Show]"

Comment: I think @Ameen is asking about stacking on top of a screen. Have you seen this dropdown toggle on top of a screen- especially where the notifications are dismissable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can group notifications into 2 categories - Urgent and Important and Important but not Urgent (anything that's not important shouldn't be in the notifications).

Among these categories, the Urgent and Important notifications should be shown singly whereas the Important but not Urgent notifications can be stacked on one another to save space.

What is Urgent and Important would perhaps consist of the following:

- notifications that requires users' immediate attention and action
- anything users must know, e.g. COVID situation on the transport vehicle, status of test results, any delays in schedules, and etc.